# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

When I run in terminal:

```
sudo spark-submit --master local --class xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxJob --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.resource=xxx.conf' /home/xxxxx/workspace/prueba/pruebas/target/scala-2.11/MiPrueba.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at pureconfig.DurationUtils$.words(DurationUtils.scala:36)
    at pureconfig.DurationUtils$.pureconfig$DurationUtils$$expandLabels(DurationUtils.scala:38)
    at pureconfig.DurationUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(DurationUtils.scala:53)
    at pureconfig.DurationUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(DurationUtils.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:338)
    at pureconfig.DurationUtils$.(DurationUtils.scala:53)
    at pureconfig.DurationUtils$.(DurationUtils.scala)
    at pureconfig.DurationReaders$class.$init$(BasicReaders.scala:114)
    at pureconfig.ConfigReader$.(ConfigReader.scala:121)
    at pureconfig.ConfigReader$.(ConfigReader.scala)
    at xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.config.package$Config$.load(package.scala:67)
    at xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.job.xxxxJob$class.main(XXXxxx.scala:23)
    at xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx......Job$.main(Xxxxxxxxxxxx.scala:19)
    at xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx..main(XXXXXXxxxxxxxx.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Build definitions:

> version := "0.1"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies:

```
val dependFullList = spark ++ hadoop ++ apisDownload ++ configuration
```

configuration:

```
  val configuration = Seq(
    "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.9.2",
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
    "org.lz4" % "lz4-java" % "1.4.1"
  )
```

Spark:

```
  val spark = Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % Versions.spark % "provided" exclude("javax.jms", "jms"),
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % Versions.spark % "provided",
    "com.databricks" %% "spark-xml" % "0.4.1"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mrpowers/spark-daria
  )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run `spark-submit --version`?

Comment: spark-submit --version --> 2.4.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing scala versions. 
Spark 2.4.2 doesn't support scala 2.11. Switch to Spark 2.4.0 or replace your libraries with scala 2.12 versions.

https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-2.html

Note that Scala 2.11 support is deprecated from 2.4.1 onwards. As of 2.4.2, the pre-built convenience binaries are compiled for Scala 2.12. Spark is still cross-published for 2.11 and 2.12 in Maven Central, and can be built for 2.11 from source.